# Distributing for App Store using beta versions of Xcode

Tags: xcode, beta

When I try to distribute an app I get this error:

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and
>   failed to do so because of the following issues.
>
> **No matching provisioning profiles found for "Application/TheApp.app"**
>
> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified
>   entitlements: application-identifier, beta-reports-active,
>   keychain-access-groups.

I don't really understand what that error means. Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't submit an app to App Store with beta software, you have to wait GM release.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#)

> New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with
>   release versions of Xcode 5. Do not submit apps built with beta
>   software, as beta versions are for development and testing only.
>
> Xcode 6 beta, iOS 8 beta, and OS X Yosemite Developer Preview are
>   pre-release software. Your use is subject to and licensed only under
>   the terms and conditions of the iOS Developer Program License
>   Agreement ("iOS PLA"), including any applicable consent to collect
>   diagnostic data set forth therein. If you have not agreed to the iOS
>   PLA, you are not permitted to use this software.

**9 Sep. 2014**

You may now use **Xcode 6 GM seed** to submit apps to the App Store and Mac App Store.

Comment: Cool thanks for the quick and detailed answer. That means I can't distribute anything written with swift right?

Comment: Okay, well back to objective c again I guess. :)

Comment: Does this mean you can't distribute any beta software either? Such as via Test Flight?

Comment: @Dean this rule applies to Apple's App stores, I have no knowledge about Test Flight rules/policies.

Comment: @Dean you can submit to testflight.

Comment: Just to confirm, I can submit my app as soon and the GM is out? And that will likely be next Monday?

Comment: @user3746428 yes with GM all fine.

Comment: So we cannot submit an iOS8-ready version of an app before the official XCode6 is released!?

Comment: @AXE yes it is correct you have to wait GM release of Xcode and official release of IOS8.

Comment: Thanks!
Seems kind of stupid, though. Users will update their devices with the new OS and the apps will look odd/crash. Then thousands of apps will fly to Apple on a single day and it will take significant time for the review team to pass them through. Or am I missing something!?

Comment: There is a window between GM release and end user release they do ok and as I can see in years most of the people are not keen to do it quick.

Comment: So I would submit my app as soon as the GM is out, and then would set the release date to be on the same day as iOS 8 is out? Even though my app works on iOS 7 and 8? Sorry, I just want to make sure since I was expecting to be able to submit it now. Kind of disappointing.

Comment: "beta-reports-active" is equal to 1 during upload using XCode 6 GM. What does 1 means? Any help?

Comment: @sergiou87 did you refresh your developer profile in Xcode? Xcode / Preferences / Account / View Details and click refresh icon.

Comment: Yep, that didn't work. I finally fixed it by going to my Project -> Capabilities, enable some (like Keychain Sharing), wait for it, disable it again. That created an empty entitlements file and it just worked :D

Comment: Neither of those solutions worked for me... Xcode 6 GM, refreshed developer profile, enabled/disabled capabilities... still getting the same error! Any other solutions out there?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same error till I revoke and request new iPhone Distribution certificate from Apple.

1. Go to developer.apple.com, open Certificates.
2. If you have 2 or less certificates for Distribution you can create new one. But if you have 3 you need to revoke one and then create new one.
3. Go to Provision Profiles and select your profile. Change old certificate to just created certificate. Download provision profile.
4. Now build your app.

Comment: What if we are trying to export a previously created archive for archive distribution? We cannot rebuild if we are using an archive that is already created - so are we out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I think you can, starting now ;)

I just received the mail from :

> To prepare your apps for the App Store, download and build with the iOS 8 and Xcode 6 GM seeds from the iOS Dev Center. With these latest seeds, Swift is now final and you can submit your iOS apps written with Swift to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a beta version of Xcode, and you have regenerated all your certificates, and you are doing everything you should and it is still not happening; this is what worked for me:

**1. Backup your code, 2. delete your project, 3. recreate the project anew, 4. add your code back in** and *voila* successful build for validation and submission to the App Store.

Comment: That might be a solution to trivial projects. It seems like an easy way, but I would not recommend it unless no other option is available.

Comment: @chrs - agreed.  This solution is for when no other option is available.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack, you can replace the build version number in the system to cheat to the system.

1. System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
2. Replace the build version of the beta for the last release version, in my case for 10.15.5 is 19G73