# Ad Hoc testing with Xcode 6 (beta 5)

Tags: ios, xcode, adhoc

When trying to validate my SWIFT app on Xcode 6 (beta 5), I get the same error as in [Distributing for App Store using beta versions of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171023/distribute-app-for-app-store-using-xcode-6-beta-5).

I understand we can't submit to app store, but is there a way to test SWIFT apps with an ad hoc distribution? Trying to get the app ready by the Xcode 6 GA time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can go ahead and export the archive for ad hoc distribution even though the validate fails, the ipa will install and run fine.