# No matching provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile

Though I had been a while without seeing such an error, I recently got this message, when trying to archive an app written in Objectiv-C:

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues.
>
> No matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/myApp.app"
>
> None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups.

I haven’t changed anything in my settings, and this error seems to appear with recent versions of Xcode. I am using Xcode 6.3.2.
When I wanted to archive an app written in swift, I did not have this problem.
I do not see why the language would be related to the provisioning profiles, but that just something I noticed.

I tried to use a brand new provisioning profile, but it didn’t make any difference.
I also tried Refresh accounts from Xcode preferenced, but again with no luck.
Of course I looked for some solution on the net, but everything failed.

Comment: Check that your certificate hasn't expired

Comment: How do I do that? Is it possible that it would expire for an objectiv-c app and not for a swift one?

Comment: Or I could be using a different one without knowing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Refresh Provisionning profiles from XCode - Preferences - Accounts - View Details - refresh button
2. Connect to Itunes Member Center to agree on the new Apple Developer Agreement
3. It will take some minutes to propagate through the network if you click on the agree button (I had to wait 10 minutes)
4. eventually refresh again your provisioning profiles in XCode And eventually, check that your Distribution certificate is still valid in the iTunes Member Center

Comment: Thanks. Step 1, I have done this countless times. Step 2, I just took a look but do not see any requirement to agree on anything I haven't already agreed on. Step 4 I do not see anything related to the app I am concerned with, in iTunes Member Center that is not still valid. In other words I do not really know what to do. Could I be missing something?

Comment: maybe you can focus on this part of the error? "None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: application-identifier, beta-reports-active, keychain-access-groups."

Comment: http://blog.landfront.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/iTunesConnect.png maybe your Provisioning profile doesn't have exactly all the necessary entitlements settings?

Comment: I have tried to add beta-reports-active to my plist, set it to YES, then NO.
It doesn't seem to change anything either way. What exactly is supposed to match what? When I read "None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements", it sounds like martian to me, because I have only one distribution provisioning profile for this app and I have never intentionally set any entitlement.

Comment: For my "Provisioning profile doesn't have all the necessary entitlements settings" I don't see where to set any entitlement setting when I create a Provisioning profile. I may have missed a button or some sort.

Comment: Is your xCode a beta version ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171023/distributing-for-app-store-using-beta-versions-of-xcode

Comment: No it is not a beta version.