# XCode 7 require code signing on cocoapods frameworks?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

In Xcode 6.4(I don't have to code sign the frameworks of cocoapods, so i can submit it to AppStore)
[image: Xcode 6 archiving]

But when Archive & Upload on XCode 7(beta) , all of my frameworks are not code signed, and I was unable to upload it to AppStore.
Got an error: "ITMS-90035: Code object is not signed at all"
Any suggestion?
[image: Xcode 7 archiving]

Comment: You can't submit an app to App Store with beta software, you have to wait GM release.
see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171023/distributing-for-app-store-using-beta-versions-of-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit an application to App Store with beta version of Xcode, you need to wait for the full version OR gold master.